# Multiply hourly values with daily constant in a memory effective way

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One with an hourly index:

```
df_hourly = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[{0: 1, 1: 2}],
    index=pd.date_range(
        pd.Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00+02:00', tz='CET'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00+02:00', tz='CET'),
        freq='h',
        closed="left"
    )
)
```

and one with a daily index:

```
df_daily = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[{0: 3, 1: 4}],
    index=pd.date_range(
        pd.Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00+02:00', tz='CET'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00+02:00', tz='CET'),
        freq='d',
        closed="left"
    )
)
```

I'd like to multiply those dataframes:

```
df_daily.reindex(df_hourly.index, method="ffill").mul(df_hourly)
```

The problem with this approach is that the reindexing causes a spike in memory consumption (long index, lots of columns).

Is there a solution which is at least as fast and uses less memory?
Somehow I was hoping I could omit the reindexing just for the purpose of broadcasting the value per day.